# What is the equivalent of STR( column1,12,11) in SQL Server for POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql

What is the equivalent of STR( column1,12,11)  in SQL Server for POSTGRESQL?

> STR( column1,12,11)

Comment: see: [Using PostgreSQL CAST To Convert a Value of One Type to Another](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/)

Comment: or: `select ((2.0/3)::DECIMAL(12,11))::CHAR(13);` result: `0.66666666667`

Comment: So what does `str()` do?